# PL/SQL insert list items into table if they dont exists already

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm really new to PL/SQL and it kinda gets confusing, so here I am, asking for help.
Given a list, I need to insert those list items into a table if they don't already exist in there. I also have a table to get the types from
(tablefortypes.type === type, type2, etc....)

```
DECLARE
 List VARCHAR;
 List := ('type', 'type2', 'type3');
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO types (code, type, sth)
 VALUES (1023, &list NOT IN types.type, 0);
END;
```

Comment: Where is your list coming from? Your declaration isn't valid - a varchar has to have a size, and can't then hold more than one value, so do you really have a collection type; and is it a PL/SQL collection or one defined at schema level, so it can be used in plain SQL?

Comment: I believe you need some more learning about PL/SQL syntax and structures before approaching this; try to start inserting a single value, stored in a scalar variable, then try to insert all the values of a list (check some documentation for data structures and how to initialize and use them) and then try to insert only non existing records ( for this, I suggest looking for MERGE).

Comment: My declaration is invalid because the SQL is an explination NOT a real query. I really don't know how I should build the query up. The list is inputed by user via FORM. I just need to insert each of those values into the database, but i don't want to do them 1 by 1 since there can be up to 138 values in the list.

Comment: The actual data type of that list is important though.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of your list is important, particularly whether it is defined as a PL/SQL type (which can only be used in PL/SQL) or at schema level (which can be used in PL/SQL or plain SQL).

This uses [a built-in collection type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI4964), and uses a not-exists check to see if the value being inserted already exists:

```
declare
  list sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  list := sys.odcivarchar2list('type', 'type2', 'type3');

  insert into types (code, type, sth)
  select 1023, l.column_value, 0
  from table(list) l
  where not exists (
    select null from types t where t.type = l.column_value
  );
end;
/
```

You don't need PL/SQL for this (though your reference to Forms suggests perhaps you do have that restriction), you can do a very similar thing in plain SQL:

```
insert into types (code, type, sth)
select 1023, l.column_value, 0
from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('type', 'type2', 'type3')) l
where not exists (
  select null from types t where t.type = l.column_value
);
```

Or you can use [a `merge` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm), which will have the same effect, and again this can be used as plain SQL or within a PL/SQL block if you really need to:

```
merge into types t
using (select column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('type', 'type2', 'type3'))) l
on (l.column_value = t.type)
when not matched then
insert (code, type, sth) values (1023, l.column_value, 0);
```

The important thing to note though is that the [table collection expression `table()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30047) only works with schema-level types.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that. The simplest is to define the specific field within the record as **unique** and hence any attempt to insert a value that already exists will fail. You can then loop over all the values and handle within the loop the condition where the attempt to insert fails. Something like (pseudo-code):

```
  LOOP
     BEGIN

         INSERT INTO tablename (field1 , field2 , field3) 
              VALUES           (value1 , value2 , value3) ;

     EXCEPTION
         WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
           -- Do nothing and continue in loop...
           NULL ;
     END ;
 END LOOP ;
```

I leave for you the details of the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Or just for completeness:

```
create table demo (code integer, type varchar2(10) constraint demo_uk unique, sth integer);

declare
   list sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
   list := sys.odcivarchar2list('type', 'type2', 'type3');

   insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(demo(type)) */ into demo (code, type, sth)
   select 1023, l.column_value, 0
   from   table(list) l;
end;
```